# GWT button setEnabled null pointer exception error

Tags: java, gwt

I have 3 buttons: "pdf", "edit", "ok", each one doing his job. I have to make the button pdf unclickable when edit button is pressed and to make it clickable again when ok is pressed. The problem is that I receive null pointer exception and I don't understand why.

```
Button pdf = new Button("Print PDF");
        pdf.getElement().getStyle().setMarginRight(7, Unit.PX);
        pdf.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //doing his job
            }}, ClickEvent.getType());

        Button edit = new Button("Ret");
        edit.getElement().getStyle().setMarginRight(7, Unit.PX);
        edit.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //doing his job
                pdf.setEnabled(false); // error
            }}, ClickEvent.getType());

        Button ok = new Button("OK");
        ok.addDomHandler(new ClickHandler(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                //doing his job
                pdf.setEnabled(true); //error
            }}, ClickEvent.getType());
```

Comment: This code, as posted, will not compile. Button pdf has to either be declared as "final", or it should be a class variable.

Comment: indeed, i modified the pdf button to be final and now works perfectly

Comment: Because the answer was found I duplicate it to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare button `pdf` as `final`, that should be enough.